# SQL doesn't see alias

Tags: mysql, sql, database

```
SELECT name, 
       manufacturer, 
       prize 
FROM   products AS p 
GROUP  BY manufacturer 
HAVING prize = (
    SELECT Max(prize) 
    FROM   products p1 
    WHERE  p.`id-product` = p1.`id-product` 
    GROUP  BY p1.manufacturer DESC 
    LIMIT  1
)
```

And the error is:

> #1054 - Unknown column 'shop.p.id.product' in 'where clause'

Comment: Provide sample data and desired results.  The subquery doesn't actually make sense.  And, there is no reference to anything like `shop.p.id.product` in the query.

Comment: You GROUP BY manufacturer and SELECT name and prize?

Comment: Forpas, yes, why not?

Comment: Read this: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need correlated `subquery` instead :

```
SELECT p.name, p.manufacturer, p.prize
FROM products AS p
WHERE p.prize = (SELECT MAX(p1.prize) FROM products p1 WHERE p1.manufacturer = p.manufacturer);
```

By this way, you will get `manufacturer`s with highest price.

**EDIT :** If one `product` has same `prize` then you will need `PK` (Primary/Identity) column that specify unique sequence :

```
SELECT p.name, p.manufacturer, p.prize
FROM products AS p
WHERE p.pk = (SELECT p1.pk 
              FROM products p1 
              WHERE p1.manufacturer = p.manufacturer
              ORDER BY p1.prize DESC
              LIMIT 1
             );
```

If you are running with latest version of `MySQL`, then you can also use ranking function :

```
SELECT p.*
FROM (SELECT p.name, p.manufacturer, p.prize,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY p.manufacturer ORDER BY p.prize DESC) AS Seq
      FROM products AS p
     ) p
WHERE Seq = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query has nothing of that form.  I would recommend writing the query by qualifying *all* column references:

```
SELECT p.name, p.manufacturer, p.prize
FROM products p
GROUP BY p.manufacturer
HAVING p.prize = (SELECT MAX(p1.prize)
                  FROM products p1
                  WHERE p.`id-product` = p1.`id-product`
                  GROUP BY p1.manufacturer DESC
                  LIMIT 1
                 );
```

MySQL allows the syntax with extra columns in the `SELECT` that are not in the `GROUP BY`, so that would not (normally) generate an error.  It is not correct, though, by the rules of SQL.

I'm not sure what the subquery is supposed to be doing.  If you want the manufacturers with the highest price, then you would not use the `GROUP BY` in the subquery.

If you want the highest priced product for each manufacturer:

```
SELECT p.name, p.manufacturer, p.prize
FROM products p
HAVING p.prize = (SELECT MAX(p1.prize)
                  FROM products p1
                  WHERE p.manufacturer = p1.manufacturer
                  LIMIT 1
                 );
```

Comment: How can you `GROUP BY manufacturer` and `SELECT name, manufacturer, prize`?

Comment: Qualifying all column references doesn't help. This same error.

Comment: @forpas . . . The query would run in most versions of MySQL.  The error that the OP has mentioned does not seem related by the `GROUP BY`/`SELECT` conditions -- and, in fact, the OP's query doesn't make sense in multiple ways.  I've provided more explanation in the answer.

Comment: Your 1st version does not run in any version of MySql.